# (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing) api issue

Tags: angular, spring

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Movie } from './movie.model';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MoviesService {
  searchMovie(title: String)
  {
    const url = 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?t='+title+'&apikey=******';
    
     return this.httpClient.get(url);


    }

    saveMovie(movie:Movie)
{

  return this.httpClient.post<Movie>('http://localhost:2222/movie',movie);
}

dbmovie(movie:Movie)
{

  return this.httpClient.post<Movie>('http://localhost:2222/movie/main',movie);
}


getAll(email:String){

  return this.httpClient.get<Movie[]>(`http://localhost:2222/movie/fav/${email}`);
}
getallDetailes(){

  return this.httpClient.get<Movie[]>(`http://localhost:2222/movie/foradmin`);
}

delete(title:String,email:String){
  return this.httpClient.delete<Movie >(`http://localhost:2222/movie/${title}/${email}`);
}

deleteAdminMovie(title:String){
  return this.httpClient.delete<Movie >(`http://localhost:2222/movie/admin/${title}`);
}

getTitle(){
  return this.httpClient.get<Movie[]>(`http://localhost:2222/movie/`);
}

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read this two articles about how to ask a great question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, this would an issue from the backend side.

The BE would not be configured for allowing FE port number.